# *When* does a C++ exception blow up C code

Tags: c++, c, exception, gcc

Ok, so I need `-fexceptions` to allow a C++ exception to propagate through C code. I tried to compare the results from both C++ and C, and, from what I can tell, the compiled routines are *identical* at the assembly, even without that option [1]. Here is the test:

```
#include <unistd.h>

typedef int (*Callback)(void* param,void* buffer,int n);

void write_wrapper(int fd,const void* buffer,int n)
{
    const char* temp=(const char*)buffer;
    while(n!=0)
        {
        int k=write(fd,temp,n);
        n-=k;
        temp+=k;
        }
}

int test(Callback cb,void* cb_param)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    int n=0;
    do
        {
        n=cb(cb_param,buffer,1024);
        write_wrapper(STDOUT_FILENO,buffer,n);
        }
    while(n!=1024);
}

int test2(Callback cb,void* cb_param)
{
char more_stack_space_please[1024]={0};
cb(cb_param,more_stack_space_please,1024);
write_wrapper(STDOUT_FILENO,more_stack_space_please,1024);
test(cb,cb_param);
}
```

Here, it is up to the caller to free resources, so there should be no leak even though the callback function throws an exception.

Even though this example appears to work (tested with simple C++ driver)

```
#include "lib.h"
#include <cstdio>

class Resource
    {
    public:
        Resource()
            {fprintf(stderr,"A Resource\n");}

        ~Resource()
            {fprintf(stderr,"Not a Resource\n");}
    };

int main()
    {
    try
        {
        Resource foo;
        test([](void* cb_param,void* buffer, int n)->int
            {
            Resource bar;
            throw "test";
            },nullptr);
        test2([](void* cb_param,void* buffer, int n)->int
            {
            throw "test2";
            },nullptr);
        }
    catch(const char* err)
        {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s\n",err);
        return -1;
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

, I have got uncaught exception errors from GTK callbacks. My thoughts:

- GTK is a shared library, so maybe it only affects the linker, and not the code generator
- GTK (and GLib) contains a lot strange hacks, that may screw things up

[1] https://godbolt.org/g/HfSnjB

Comment: "appears to work (not tested)" - hmmmmm. Do you expect *us* to test *for you*? Couldn't you have done that little bit yourself, up-front? I don't think it's too much to ask that *you* test *your* stuff before asking...

Comment: @JesperJuhl, sure, but identical assembly should be fine (if it is not a linker issue)

Comment: `*When* does a C++ exception blow up C code` before the code is used in production, but only if you're lucky.

Comment: Your godbolt view is suppressing all the interesting assembly output...

Comment: @KerrekSB, but if I disable "Filter all assembler directives", I get tons of debug information that makes it impossible to comprehend.

Comment: You don't have any exception handling code in your source code above, so why would expect the assembly to be different?

Comment: *Don't do this*. Even when you manage to solve the issue of propagating the exceptions, you can't guarantee that arbitrary C code will free resources correctly when an exception is thrown. Instead, you can try passing a `std::exception_ptr` to the upper layers and rethrow it there.

Comment: To add to that: [Don't allow exceptions to propagate across module boundries](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/c-coding-standards/0321113586/ch63.html)

Comment: @milleniumbug I said *the resource management is handled by the client, so there should be no resources to free from the C code.

Comment: The only way you can guarantee if an external library doesn't allocate resources internally is to audit it (and every new release) or write it yourself. This doesn't seem to be the case for neither GTK or glib.

Comment: @milleniumbug Yes, but resource allocation alone cannot *block* the exception. I was asking for why propagation brakes. Also I ask because: I want to write a library usable from C, but do not want the caller to have to catch exceptions inside its callbacks.

Comment: @user877329 *but do not want the caller to have to catch exceptions inside its callbacks.* Then your library simply **CAN NOT** throw any exceptions - you have no control over what users of your library can do, so there's no way you can guarantee they'll use a compiler that documents and guarantees what you want (if such a compiler even exists....)  Because if the compiler doesn't actually document the behavior you desire, the next simple update may very well break everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with this question, is it asks what is the defined behavior for an undefined result.

The C standard does not describe the behavior when an exception is thrown through a C function, because it shouldn't happen.

The C++ standard does not explain the mechanism for an uncaught exception dropping through a C function because it shouldn't happen.

### A practical example

Windows  Visual C++ uses the fs: segment register for thread local storage, and a particular slot in the thread-local data segment to create a linked list of catch frames.

When a C++ exception is thrown, the linked list is inspected for destructors of stack objects, and a suitable catch frame.

The C compiler may not be aware of the C++ usage of these resources, and be able to re-use the slots for a different purpose.  If the slots are used for an incompatible function, then a crash will happen.

A particular platform and compiler may support this, but you would be at the whim of the platform for such.

gcc is a C compiler, so does not throw exceptions.  It can create code which is exception aware as it supports `-fexception`.

[gnu compiler : using exceptions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html)  suggests compiling the C code with -fexceptions and says

> In particular, unwinding into a frame with no exception handling data will cause a runtime abort.

Although the context of that statement does not describe whether that is due to being debugged clause, or due to the exception mechanism identifying an illegal state and causing an abort.

The actual implementation would be hardware and OS specific, which is not specified in the question, and for a specific answer, these should be specified.

- C++ does not have a compatibility ABI.  Calling through C++ objects compiled with different compilers does not give a guarantee of working.
- exceptions thrown between different modules is not recommended, as even the implementation on a compiler has produced code which is not intra-version compatible.
- Assuming that you have control over both the C and C++ code, ensure the C is safe by enabling the exceptions and possibly compiling the C as C++ (with an `extern "C"` wrapper, ensuring it is a fully C++ compilation unit.

Comment: Though this is a good answer, I am asking for GCC specific details. But if this applies, I guess that `-fexceptions` flag reserves some space, that otherwise would have been useable.

Comment: @user877329 I don't think you mentioned in the question that you're asking about GCC specific details.

Comment: @user2079303 Read the tags

Comment: @user877329 I've read the tags and I've seen that you've tagged gcc. That tells me that gcc is somehow related to your question, but you haven't explained how it is relevant (until your comment to this answer).